# django manytomany relation : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django, many-to-many, relation

I'v got problem with 'self' manytomany relation in Django:

My models :

```
class EcomProduct(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='EcomProductToProduct', symmetrical=False),


class EcomProductToProduct(models.Model):
    from_ecom_product = models.ForeignKey(EcomProduct,related_name='from_ecomproduct')
    to_ecom_product = models.ForeignKey(EcomProduct,related_name='to_ecomproduct')
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'ecom_product_to_product'
```

Now in views.py I need to get all products related to the particular product:

```
def show_product(request, ecomproduct_slug, template_name="catalog/product.html"):
     p = get_object_or_404(EcomProduct, slug=ecomproduct_slug)
     related_products_to_product = p.products.all() #it doesn't work
```

And I receive message:

```
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Question is how to get all related products to the particular product ?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Please post repr(p) and repr(p.products)

Answer (score 5):

You have a comma after the declaration of `programs` in your `EcomProduct` model definition. That turns it into a tuple, which you certainly don't want.